# ElastAlert Error - 'No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort on

Tags: elasticsearch, yaml, elastalert

I'm testing elastalert using the command 'elastalert-test-rule'. 
And, I got the error message.

```
elastalert_error - {'message': "Error running query: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'No mapping found for [@timestamp]
in order to sort on')", 
(omission)
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(', "elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort on')"], 
'data': {'rule': 'test', 
'query': {'query': {'bool': {'filter': {'bool': {'must': [{'range': {'@timestamp': {'gt': '2022-03-10T09:03:31.454969Z', 'lte': '2022-03-10T09:08:34.454969Z'}}}, \
 {'query_string': {'query': '_type: pi_endpointincidentlogdata'}}, \
 {'query_string': {'query': 'elog_logtype: 1'}}, {'query_string': 
 {'query': 'elog_loggroup: 32 OR elog_loggroup: 64'}}, {'query_string': {'query': '_exists_ : elog_patterinfo.elog_patternname'}}, \
 {'range': {'elog_createtime': {'gte': '2022-01-03 10:33:00', 'lte': '2022-01-03 10:37:00'}}}]}}}},  
 'sort': [{'@timestamp': {'order': 'asc'}}]}}}
```

I cannot understand the error because I didn't declare the @timestamp range and sort in the filter.

This is my rule file

```
> name: test 
> type: frequency 
> index: pi_202202* 
> num_events: 1 
> timeframe: 
>   minutes: 5
> 
> filter:
>       - query:
>           query_string:
>             query: "_type: pi_endpointincidentlogdata"
>       - query:
>           query_string:
>             query: "elog_logtype: 1"
>       - query:
>           query_string:
>             query: "elog_loggroup: 32 OR elog_loggroup: 64"
>       - query:
>           query_string:
>             query: "_exists_ : elog_patterinfo.elog_patternname"
>       - range:
>           elog_createtime:
>             gte: "2022-01-03 10:33:00"
>             lte: "2022-01-03 10:37:00"
> 
> alert:
> - "email"
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because ElastAlert uses the [`@timestamp` field](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ruletypes.html#timestamp-type) by default to sort your data.

You can change that in the `timestamp_field` configuration and use another field that is present in your data.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem.
elasticalert is trying to load the following mappings =>

`find / -name es_mappings`

- elastalert_error.json
- elastalert.json
- elastalert_status.json
- past_elastalert.json
- silence.json

The problem was the index_template. When Elastalert was trying to create its own mapping, it conflicted with an index_template and was unable to add its own mapping. Deleting the relevant index_template and re-running the `elasticalert-create-index` command fixed the issue.